# True or False statement: If $\hat{x}$ is the unique solution to $Ax = b$ then $\hat{x}= (A^T A)^{-1} A^T b$

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I believe this statement is true according to Theorem 14 since x hat is the unique solution to Ax=b? But I am not too sure?

Comment: The statements a, b, c, and (4) are logically equivalent. If one is true then they are all true. This theorem is in fact correct for linear least-squares. Does this clear everything up?

Comment: what book is it?

Comment: Linear Algebra And Its Applications Fifth ed